# SyndicationFeed AttributeExtensions namespace prefix

Tags: c#, .net, rss, syndication

I'm adding some custom iTunes podcast tags to a RSS Feed.

```
        feed.AttributeExtensions.Add(new XmlQualifiedName(itunesPrefix, 
            "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"), itunesNs);

        var extensions = feed.ElementExtensions;

        extensions.Add(new SyndicationElementExtension("category", itunesNs, "Business"));

        var categoryElem = XName.Get("category", itunesNs);

        extensions.Add(
            new XElement(categoryElem,
                new XAttribute("text", "Sports &amp; Recreation"),
                    new XElement(categoryElem,
                        new XAttribute("text", "Amateur")
                    )
            ).CreateReader()
        );
```

The output is:

```
<itunes:category>Business</itunes:category>
<category text="Sports &amp;amp; Recreation" xmlns="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
  <category text="Amateur">
  </category>
</category>
```

Why is it that `SyndicationElementExtension` correctly adds the namespace prefix "itunes" but passing an XmlReader instance does not?

The output I expected is:

```
<itunes:category text="Sports &amp;amp; Recreation">
  <itunes:category text="Amateur">
  </itunes:category>
</itunes:category>
```

Answer (score 0):

You know what I found the easiest to do was to just create it normally and then use Feedburner to submit it to iTunes and make iTunes compatible.